# An inequality proof

Tags: calculus

Let $n$ be a positive integer. By Bernoullis' Inequality which states that
$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$ for $x\geq -1$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So that $(1-x^2)^n \geq 1-nx^2$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Proof that $$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx \geq \frac{4}{3\sqrt{n}}$$

---

Could anyone give me a hint? I would like to start it with even function, but in vain.

Answer (score 5):

[Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) states that $(1+y)^r \ge 1+ry$ for all $r \ge 0$ and $y \ge -1$.

By using Bernoulii's inequality for $y = -x^2$ and $r = n$ you get that $(1-x^2)^n \ge 1-nx^2$ for all $-1 \le x \le 1$. Note that this is slightly different than what you have.

Also, since $(1-x^2)^n \ge 0$ for all $-1 \le x \le 1$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^n\,dx \ge \int_{-1/\sqrt{n}}^{1/\sqrt{n}}(1-x^2)^n\,dx$.

Can you use these two inequalities together to solve the problem?

Comment: Well done!  +1 - Mark

Comment: Sorry for my wrong typing the Bernoulli's inequality....